# Hyphen as blend_char doesn't seem to work

Tags: sphinx

```
MariaDB> select id,name from t where type='B' and name='Foo-Bar';
+----------------+---------+
| item_source_id | name    |
+----------------+---------+
|        2000245 | Foo-Bar |
+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
index base_index { # Don't use this directly; it's for inheritance only.
  blend_chars = +, &, U+23, U+22, U+27, -, /
  blend_mode = trim_none, trim_head, trim_tail, trim_both
}
source b_source : base_source {
  sql_query = select id,name from t where type='B'
  sql_field_string = name
}
index b_index_lemma : base_index {
  source = b_source
  path = /path/b_index_lemma
  morphology = lemmatize_en_all
}
```

```
SphinxQL> select * from b_index_lemma where match('Foo-Bar');
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Other Sphinx queries have results, so the problem isn't e.g. that the index is empty. Yet the hyphenated form does not, and I'd like it to. Am I misusing `blend_chars`-cum-`blend_mode`?

Comment: Does `match('Foo\-Bar')` work? as - is also a syntax operator. Also what about `match('"Foo Bar"')`?

Comment: @barryhunter, `match('Foo\-Bar')` matches nothing; `match('"Foo Bar"')` matches the result; `match('"Foo-Bar"')` matches nothing.

Comment: What about `match('FooBar')` ? Wonder if it means the the blend is working duiring index, its just the not working during query. Which as say is more compliated due to - also being syntax. Then again maybe `match('Foo\\-Bar')` will work? Need two slashes, one is for the sphinx full-text query parsing, but need ANOTHER, for the SQL query parsing (extracting the string from the query)